# How to convert bit type to bytea type in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to convert bit type into bytea in postgresql.
Like this.

```
select (b'1010110011001100' & b'1011000011110000')::bytea;
```

However, error occured

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type bit to bytea
LINE 1: select (b'1010110011001100' & b'1011000011110000')::bytea;
```

I just wanted to do an operation on bit strings and convert to bytea type.

Comment: do you analyze it ?https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-binarystring.html?

Comment: Yes,I've already read it.But, I could not find any clue to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why did you want to save as `bytea` and what is your expect result from your query

Comment: Originally the data is stored as bytea type in database .To do bit-wise operation, it is converted from bytea to bit. However the calculated bit can not be reversed to bytea.

Comment: @Boblishus I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the bit value to hex and use `decode()`:

```
select decode(to_hex((b'1010110011001100' & b'1011000011110000')::int), 'hex')

 decode 
--------
 \xa0c0
(1 row)
```

Comment: This seems to be correct.However,in case of 300 digits bit, error occured `ERROR:  integer out of range`. I want to do bit-wise operation with over 1000 digits bit.

Comment: The calculated bits may have to be divided into a small range bits.And then,convert the bits to bytea like you suggested.

Comment: One way is to divide text representation into 32 hex digits parts (with bigint). You can also try [pg-bignum](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-bignum) extension.

Comment: Ugly PostgreSQL, even  nowadays (2019!) no option to **efficient cast from `varbit` to `bytea`**!?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `bit varying` type's `send` function to get the external binary form of a bit string as a `bytea` and then pass that to the `substr` function to chop off the initial 4-byte bit length field.

```
SELECT substr(varbit_send(b'1010110011001100' & b'1011000011110000'), 5);
```

```
substr | \xa0c0
```

Note that the final byte will contain unused (cleared) bits if the bit length of the bit string was not a whole multiple of 8 bits.

Doing this will incur some extra copying in memory, so it's not as efficient as one might hope, but it's better than the other proposal of reinterpreting the bit string as an integer, encoding it into hex, and then decoding the hex into a `bytea`, as that causes leading zero nibbles to be dropped and fails when the number of significant nibbles is odd:

```
SELECT decode(to_hex((b'1010110011001100' & b'0101010011110000')::int), 'hex');
```

```
ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the "external binary form" trick to go in the opposite direction, as base types' `receive` functions do not accept a `bytea` datum as an argument.

Answer (score -3):

```
select decode((b'1010110011001100' & b'1011000011110000')::text,'escape')
```

or

```
select ((b'1010110011001100' & b'1011000011110000')::text)::bytea
```